# reformat date coming form array javascript/React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i am trying to figure out how to reformat a date coming from an array... Example:

```
data: [{id: "1213" startDate: "2020-04-22T17:20:35.797Z" endDate: "2021-04-22T17:20:35.797Z"}]

<div>{data.startDate}</div>
```

currently the date is displaying as 2020-04-22T17:20:35.797Z. My question is how do i reformat the date to show as 04/22/2020?

Comment: If would be nice if you could accept one of the answers or if they do not solve your problem, comment them and explain why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert your date to a js date:

```
const date = new Date(data.startDate);
```

Then use the `toLocaleDateString` function to convert to local date string:

```
<div>{date.toLocaleDateString()}</div>
```

To batch convert your data array, you can do that:

```
const newData = data.map(item => {
    const startDate = new Date(item.startDate);
    const endDate = new Date(item.endDate);
    return {id: item.id, startDate: startDate.toLocaleDateString(), endDate: endDate.toLocaleDateString()}
})
```

Comment: thanks! the problem i am running into now is i am using map. so for example:      {this.state.data.map((datas, index) => (
        <p>{datas.startDate}</p>
    ))} so setting a const date = new Date(data.startDate); seems to be causing an issue since the map function is relying on datas and not data now...hope that makes sense. new to this

Comment: I have edited my answer and added the code to batch convert your data array

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Convert startDate to a javascript Date object and then use normal formatting to get the desired output. Ouput will be array of formatted dates

```js
let arr = [{
  id: "1213",
  startDate: "2020-04-22T17:20:35.797Z",
  endDate: "2021-04-22T17:20:35.797Z"
}];

const ret = arr.map(item => {
 let startDate = new Date(item.startDate);
 let datestring =
    startDate.getDate() +
    "-" +
    (startDate.getMonth() + 1) +
    "-" +
    startDate.getFullYear();
 return datestring;
});

console.log(ret);
```